# When filling a hole with loose earth, should there be extra?

Tags: outdoor

I just want to know if what I'm being told is right, or am i getting bamboozled.

Following modifications to my house, I was left with a 8' x 8' x 6' hole on the side of my house.

Thing is they filled the hole, but added maybe half a feet extra on top (where we wanted it to be flush with the ground, to do a patio on top)

[image]

He then told us to just watet it down for hours at a time every few days, and it should fit in over a few weeks.

Is that right or did he just put us some extra dirt on top that we are gonna have to get to the city dump?

Comment: have you never dug a hole in the ground and then filled it back when you were a child?  ...... get a shovel, dig a hole and then put the dirt back into the hole without tamping it down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should have compacted the fill in shallow layers to speed up the settlement, in which case settlement would be essentially done in maybe a year. 
If they just filled the hole, that will take many years to fully settle, and there isn't much you can do from the surface now.

For loose fill, that's probably about the amount of soil you need for it to eventually be level and not leave a dish in the yard.

Unfortunately, you'll need to rethink your patio plans. If they didn't compact it in layers, anything you put there in the next many years will seriously settle and be a mess.

Comment: Rethink, or just know it will go to pot, and simply throw some cheap pavers down and enjoy the summer, after you've compacted or settled what you can.

Comment: I guess my question was more about the watering it down for 2-3 hours every few days... Seems like a huge waste of water

Comment: You're correct.  For a hole that deep, the water will just create other problems.

Comment: Put down cheap pavers, and each year pull them up, fill a bit, then enjoy the rest of the summer.